# Lenovo ThinkPad e540 function key disables after loading the system

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, keyboard-layout, thinkpad, function-keys

ENV: Lenovo e540 with Ubuntu 18.04.

While on BIOS or pre loading of the Ubuntu, the function key is lit up and seems to be working. However once Ubuntu load, even before logging in, the function key goes off and I am not able to turn it back on. I have tried several issues and thought it might be related to keyboard configuration or keyboard display settings but I could not find an Issue.

As for now the function key seems to be active all the time even though it is visually turned off (no green light over button) thus I am not able to use my <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys. <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> is not helping. Any ideas how to move forward to get my <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> keys back?

Comment: I have the same problem with my T480s